# How to download the latest changed source code and files from a heroku app?

Tags: python, heroku

**My Question:**

I have a **[heroku](https://heroku.com) app using python** which is basically just a **twitter bot** where people mention the account and the bot auto-replies.
I have deployed it using the **Heroku CLI**. Now to make sure I don't process the same query multiple times, I *save every query in a `json` file and then reset it to an **empty dict** every week*.

```
with open("weekly_tweets.json", "r") as f:
    tweets_dict = json.load(f)

if matched_name in tweets_dict: ## already processed query for player that week
    api.update_status("blah blah") ##do something

else: ##new query
    tweet = api.update_with_media("other blah blah") ##do something else
    
    ## Here's where I update the json file for every new query weekly
    tweets_dict[matched_name] = tweet.id ##update dict
    with open("weekly_tweets.json", "w") as f:
        json.dump(tweets_dict, f) ##save dict
```

**The Issue:**

I want to change stuff in the app later on. To do that, I thought cloning from the heroku app by doing

`heroku git:clone -a APP-NAME` would give me the latest version of the `json` file.

***That was not the case and I actually got the same empty `json` file that I pushed during my first deployment.***
This is an issue because if I make changes and push now, I'll process all the request I have *already* processed last week.

---

**The Actual Question**: How do I get the current version of the repository with the updated `json` file so as to keep in sync with my bot? What options do I have here (preferably free), if anything at all?

Thanks in Advance! In case it matters, the full code is [here](https://github.com/sharmaabhishekk/wosonars-code/tree/master/src)

Comment: Every file saved by the application is temporary, and it gets deleted at the next restart (ephemeral file system), you cannot persist data for more than 24hrs. The `git:clone` also copies the source pushed by you, not the data managed by the application

Comment: Ohh, seems like my very premise was wrong. Would you happen to have any suggestions as to how to save, read and write files for a longer duration while having a app on heroku (more than 24 hours)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Heroku file system is [ephemeral](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#ephemeral-filesystem): files saved by the application are temporary) and are removed at every Dyno restart and application re-deployment.
The Dyno reboot **occurs at least** every 24rhs.

In [Files on Heroku](https://medium.com/geekculture/files-on-heroku-cd09509ed285) you can see read several options on how to save files on external storage.

Storing the file with your source code is a possibility: using PyGithub the application can commit/push a file into your repository (even if it is private)

```
github = Github('personal_access_token')
# get repo by name
repository = github.get_user().get_repo('my_repo')

# define path in the repository
filename = 'files/file.json'
# JSON content
content = '{}'
# create with commit message
f = repository.create_file(filename, "create_file via PyGithub", content)
```

Comment: This seems to solve my issue, thanks.

In case anyone's seeing this later, another way to do this would probably be to connect Google Drive to Python

Comment: Thanks for the feedback Abhishek, I will explore the option and add it to the blog post.